# facebook Graph API のv2.0以降でread_streamのパーミッションを獲得できるか？

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

facebook Graph API が5月からv2.0以降しか使えなくなりますが、v2.0ではread_streamの権限を使えなくてどうしたものかと思っています。
特にわからないのが以下の英文です。

The read_stream permission is only granted for apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available.
For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

何度読み返してもドキュメントと突き合わせてもグループで質問してもいまいちはっきりせずもやもやしています。

私は現在facebookのOAuth認証でログインしてユーザーのタイムライン的なものをGraph APIで取得して表示するサイトを作成しています。
私のサイトでread_streamが絶対に貰えないのならいろいろ諦めるのですが、自分の英語力ではそれが判断出来ずに困ってます。

一体、read_streamの権限はどんな場合に付与される可能性があるのでしょうか？
わかるかたがいましたらご教授ください。